# Can't update AWS lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, updates

I'm trying to update a method in a file in AWS lambda function. Previously, the method accepted URLs such as

```
https://yh74mgrokc.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ga/answer/qn_type?tag=alexa
```

I updated the function to accept URL like the ones below, as well as new tags like to and from.

```
https://yh74mgrokc.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ga/answer/qn_type?tag=alexa&from=2020-05-29&to=2021-05-29
```

So, I modified one of the methods as follows:

```
exports.getAnswerQnTypeSchema = [
    query('tag')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('tag is required'),
    query().custom((query) => {

        const allowedKeys = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "tag",
            "from",
            "to"
        ];
        for (const key of Object.keys(query)) {
            if (!allowedKeys.includes(key)) {
                throw new Error(`Unknown property: ${key} please resolve`,query);
            }
        }

        return true;
    })
];
```

to allow for 'from' and 'to' tags. Then I redeployed the function and uploaded the updated lambda function. But still the function works as the previous version. when I send the request

```
https://yh74mgrokc.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ga/answer/qn_type?tag=alexa&from=2020-05-29&to=2021-05-29
```

It does not support the from and to tags, and the error message is as follows:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is the case. I'm new to AWS services, and any assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to provide details of your API gateway setup. Only you know what you did with it. Maybe you assigned to a function version or alias? Sadly your question lacks details.

Comment: Have you tested it in isolation in your console?

Comment: I had chosen a wrong lambda function. that's why the updated code didn't work. Make sure whether the api gateway is accessing your currently editing lambda function.